# StringBuffer , StringBuidler

Tags: stringbuffer

StringBuidler sb="ram"
StringBuffer sf = "ram"

Both throws comile time error .
Please explain Why??????

Comment: What language is this meant to be?

Answer (score 4):

There's no promotion from String to StringBuilder/Buffer. Try

```
StringBuilder = new StringBuilder("ram")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because StringBuilder and StringBuffer  isn't strings.
You need to write

```
sb = new StringBuilder("ram")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because it is "StringBuilder" not "StringBuidler"?
Or maybe because you need a semi-colon between the two lines?
Or that "ram" is a string and not a StringBuilder or StringBuffer?